# Weird thing - -25 reputation from not mine post

Tags: support, reputation

I have on my profile on StackOverflow (in Reputation section) this:

```
Oct 8
-25  12:08  removed I need to create a GUI that will launch external applications using Visual Studio 2010
```

As for me this is weird, because:

1. I haven't used Windows for ~6 months
2. Even when I used Windows, I used VS 2008 only (I installed VS 2010, but I hated it)
3. I wasn't even using internet this day, had really important task to do.

So my question is, what is that?

Comment: Also don't just post [an answer that's just a bunch of links with zero explanation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ei7O7.jpg). If someone flagged an answer like that as "not an answer," I would have deleted it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question was deleted. The reputation you gained from posting an answer is reversed since the question was deleted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311002/i-need-to-create-a-gui-that-will-launch-external-applications-using-visual-studi

So it's not really negative reputation (in the same sense as downvotes), it's just StackOverflow reclaiming points awarded for a question deemed inappropriate.

Comment: True, just note that if post is more than 60 days old and has score of +3 or more, the user will keep the reputation gained from it.